# ES6 unexpected token

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to use es6 to keep this code a little cleaner however my code creates a fatal error `unexpected token`. What am I doing wrong here?

Example: `Works - old javascript`

```
('/admin/candidate_profile/edit/contact_details/' + this.props.candidateUserId)
```

Example: `Doesn't work - es6`

```
{`/admin/candidate_profile/edit/contact_details/${this.props.candidateUserId}`}
```

Comment: Where did these brackets { } come from?

Comment: Just keep the `(...)` instead of the `{...}`?

Comment: I thought they were required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to set a variable equal to the above statement then you don't need the curly braces. For example, the below snippet should work:

```
let foo = `/admin/candidate_profile/edit/contact_details/${this.props.candidateUserId}`;
```